# Minified version of JavaScript library under LGPL used on a site without copyright notice

Tags: javascript, licensing, libraries, lgpl

On this site [hackfind.com](http://www.hackfind.com/) the autor put minified version of my [library](http://terminal.jcubic.pl) without any copyright notice. Is this violation of the LGPL. Note that using on a site is not a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have not included the legal text that is expected of a file that is released under the LGPL license. From a legal standpoint, that makes it unclear if the LGPL really applies to your library. I would recommend that you follow the [guidelines from FSF on how to apply the (L)GPL to your code](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html).

With that out of the way, it is also a legal gray area if using a client-side JavaScript library on your site distributes that library. You can certainly interpret it that way, because the client's browser downloads the JavaScript and executes it on the client's machine.
But even if it doesn't count as distribution, it is not good manners to rip out a copyright notice and you can certainly ask the maintainer of hackfind.com to use (a local copy of) the minified version of your library that you provide already.

Answer (score 3):

From my reading of http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html and the commentary provided in [How can I legally use LGPL javascript in a commercial web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2015805/289086)

Yes.

That the code is minified in no way absolves the person using it from noting that the license of the code is LGPL and linking to the license.

Furthermore, if there are any changes based upon your library, it is necessary to release the source code in a form that is neither minified nor obfuscated.